# How do I encode an array in a form field in NodeJS' request?

Tags: php, arrays, node.js, form-data, node-request

I'm using an API that requires me to put an array in a form field. The example given is in PHP, but I'm using NodeJS. The API expects one of the fields to be an array, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

The PHP example looks like this:

```
$request->buildPostBody(array(
 'reference' => array(
 'line1' => 'Soundboard Setup',
 'line2' => 'Thank you for the order',
 'line3' => 'Our reference is: 3993029/11BD'
 ),
 'lines' => array(
 array('amount' => 50,
 'amount_desc' => 'panels',
 'description' => 'Sound buttons',
 'tax_rate' => 21,
 'price' => 5.952
 ),
 array('amount' => 1,
 'amount_desc' => '',
 'description' => 'Wooden case',
 'tax_rate' => 21,
 'price' => 249
 ),
 array('amount' => 10,
 'amount_desc' => 'hours',
 'description' => 'Support',
 'tax_rate' => 6,
 'price' => 62.5
 ),
 array('description' => 'This is a textline'))
));
```

In NodeJS it I've tried this (among other things):

```
var formData = {
  reference: [{'line1':'something'}], // <- this isn't going to fly
  lines: [{
    'amount': amount,
    'amount_desc': 'amount_desc',
    'description': 'description',
    'tax_rate': 0,
    'price': 100
  }]
};

request.post({
    url: 'https://www.factuursturen.nl/api/v1/invoices/',
    formData: formData,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(user + ':' + key).toString('base64')
    }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && [200, 201, 204].indexOf(response.statusCode) > 0) {
      console.log('posted ': ', response.statusCode);
    } else {
      console.log('problem with request: ', error, response.statusCode, body);
    }
  }
);
```

---

When I try to pass an object like so: `reference: {'line1':'foo'}` I get an error from Node:

```
node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33
  source.on('error', function() {});
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

How would I best go about shoehorning this round peg into that square hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP arrays can be arrays ***and*** they can be *associative arrays*, which are essentially objects in JavaScript.

> #### Specifying with [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)
>
> An [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.
>
> ```
> array(
>     key  => value,
>     key2 => value2,
>     key3 => value3,
>     ...
> )
> ```

In JavaScript the above would essentially be *just* an **object**

```
{
    key: 'value',
    key2: 'value2'
    key3: 'value3'
    ...
}
```

It will not be an object wrapped inside an array `[{…}]`, which is what you're doing with your `reference`

So to mimic the PHP structures your data should be like this:

```
var formData = {
  reference: {'line1':'something'}, // <- this should work now
  lines: [{  // <- this is still an array of objects [{}], as in PHP too, it's a nested array
    amount: amount,
    'amount_desc': 'amount_desc',
    'description': 'description',
    'tax_rate': 0,
    'price': 100
  }]
};
```

But that causes another problem as you have noticed.

---

> When I try to pass an object like so: `reference: {'line1':'foo'}` I get an error from Node:
>
> ```
> node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33
>   source.on('error', function() {});
>          ^
> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
> ```

This error is explain here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/1495
Basically `form-data` only takes simple object probably only 1 level deep.

Try this:

```
var formData = {
  'reference.line1': 'something',
  'lines[0].amount': amount,
  'lines[0].amount_desc': 'amount_desc',
  'lines[0].description': 'description',
  'lines[0].tax_rate': 0,
  'lines[0].price': 100,
};
```

Comment: Funny enough if I try that I get a strange error from node: node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33
  source.on('error', function() {});
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the way PHP arrays map to js objects @laggingreflex. I think I now only need to figure out how to encode arrays or objects into formdata fields in nodejs

Comment: your update is the correct solution. I arrived at the same result in parallel, just came here to answer my own question and saw you got there too. I think you should remove the "So your data should be like this" part.